# Merging covariance from two sets to create new covariance

Tags: math, machine-learning, statistics, computer-vision, covariance

Is there any way to combine co-variance from two data sets instead of calculating the new co-variance by merging the data. Suppose I have already calculated co-variance from 1 million data and then if I get another 2 million data that has already calculated co-variance, can i combine the already calculated co-variance to produce the new co-variance. I am mostly interested in reducing the computation that is required when i calculate the co-variance from the combined 3 million data.

This can be easily done for mean.
new mean = (data_size_1* mean_1 + data_size_2*mean_2)/((data_size_1 + data_size_2)

Is there any similar way to calculate co-variance so that i can take advantage of the pre-computed data. I can also store some information while calculating co-variance of data_size_1 and data data_size_2 if that can help me to find the new  merged co-variance easily.

Comment: Do you have *just* the covariances, or do you have other information such as the means and variances?

Comment: @john Coleman, I have mean ,eigen values and covariance  of two data sets stored in files. The dimension of both the data sets is same. I am basically trying to combine the principal component analysis of two data sets with reduced computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Covariance Update Formula]

The complete derivation is given in this pdf http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2008/086212.pdf

Comment: is n1 the # of data and n2 the # of data in 2? and n is n1 + n2? Also, that link requires special access

Comment: The link redirects to authentication page.

Answer (score 0):

I found formula for combining variances of two sets here:
https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/combined-variance.html

Replacing (X<sub>1</sub>–X<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> with
(X<sub>1</sub>–X<sub>c</sub>)(Y<sub>1</sub>–Y<sub>c</sub>),
and (X<sub>2</sub>–X<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> with
(X<sub>2</sub>–X<sub>c</sub>)(Y<sub>2</sub>–Y<sub>c</sub>)
gives the correct results for covariances.
Unlike the formula from the first answer, which is only approximately correct.

Here is a code fragment that combines covariances `a` and `b`
into resulting covariance `r`.

```
r.n = a.n + b.n;
r.mean_x = (a.n * a.mean_x + b.n * b.mean_x) / r.n;
r.mean_y = (a.n * a.mean_y + b.n * b.mean_y) / r.n;
r.sum = a.sum + a.n * (a.mean_x - r.mean_x) * (a.mean_y - r.mean_y)
      + b.sum + b.n * (b.mean_x - r.mean_x) * (b.mean_y - r.mean_y);
```

`a`, `b` and `r` are structs that contain:

- `n` – number of elements,
- `mean_x` – mean of X,
- `mean_y` – mean of Y,
- `sum` – the covariance multiplied by `n`.